# Why is $\langle \hat{A} \rangle = tr(\hat{\rho} \hat{A})$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, density-operator, trace

Given that $$\langle \hat{A} \rangle = \langle \psi|\hat{A}|\psi \rangle$$
Why does $\langle \hat{A} \rangle = \mathrm{tr}(\hat{\rho} \hat{A})$, where $\hat{\rho}$ is the density operator, $\hat{\rho} = |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|$?

More importantly, how does trace manifest itself in a general operator, that is not a matrix? Because at the moment, all I think about when I think "trace" is the sum of the diagonal elements, which only applies to matrices...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $\langle \textbf R \rangle =Tr \rho R$ here $\rho$ is the state density matrix](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/183270/)

Comment: All operators on a vector space can be described as matrices so I don’t know what you mean by ‘general operator, that is not a matrix’

Answer (score 0):

For a general state vector, we can express it as
$$|\psi>=\sum_{i}^N|\psi_i><\psi_i|\psi>$$

If we have an ensembles of N systems of $\sum_{i}^N n_i=N$, of which are in the state $$|1>, |2>,...,|n_i> $$

The density matrix has the following definition

$$\rho=\sum_{i}^N p_i |\psi><\psi| $$

where $$p_i=n_i/N$$

The meaning of this definition is there are N states in the ensemble , where $n_i/N$ is the ratio of the desire i state over all state.

The expected value of the operator $\hat{A}$ thus $<\hat{A}>=\sum_{i}^N p_i<\psi|̂|\psi>$

Note $Tr(̂\rho)=\sum_{j}^N <i|̂\rho|i>=\sum_{j}^N\sum_{i}^N<i|̂|j><j|i> p_i$ (Apply Identity operator)

$=\sum_{i}^N <i|̂|i>p_i$

This is precisely the statistical definition of expected value of the operator $\hat{A}$.

In quantum mechanics, every operator is also a matrix, consider the operator $\hat{A}$,  you can apply Identity operator on both sides, such that

$\hat{A}=\hat{I}\hat{A}\hat{I}=(\sum_{i}^N|i><i|)\hat{A}(\sum_{j}^N|j><j|)=\sum_{i,j}^N <i|A|j> |i><j|$

Note that $<i|A|j>$ is the matrix element of the operator $\hat{A}$

Comment: thanks for the answer! I don't understand your statement of applying the identity operator. I know that $\sum |i> <i|$ is the identity operator, but i don't see how you managed to extrac $p_i$ from it

Comment: The identity operator is the following $\hat{I}=\sum_{i}^N|i><i|$

The action of this operator on state vector gives the expression $\hat{I} |V>=\sum_{i}^N|i><i|V>$ , as you can see, the express the state vector in terms of its components and basis.

The proof exactly uses this properties.

Step 1. $Tr(\hat{A}\rho)=\sum_{j}^N <j|\hat{A}\rho|j>$ (Definition of trace, extracting the diagonal elements of the operator $\hat{A}\rho$

Step 2. Explicitly expand the expression of the bracket gives $Tr(\hat{A}\rho)=\sum_{j}^N\sum_{i}^N<i|̂|j><j|i> p_i$

Step 3. <i|j> dirac delta function

Comment: @wongtom please use `\rangle` and `\langle` for brakets insteads of < and >.